# What is difference between `mut a: &T` and `a: &mut T`?

Tags: reference, rust, mutable

Could someone explain what is the difference between these two and when is `mut a: &T` most often used?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Function parameters and let bindings in Rust are proper patterns, like those at the left of `=>` in match (except that let and parameter patterns must be *irrefutable*, that is, they must always match). `mut a` is just a part of pattern syntax and it means that `a` is a mutable binding. `&mut T`/`&T`, on the other hand, is a type - mutable or immutable reference.

There are four possible combinations of `mut` in references and patterns:

```
    a: &T      // immutable binding of immutable reference
mut a: &T      // mutable binding of immutable reference
    a: &mut T  // immutable binding of mutable reference
mut a: &mut T  // mutable binding of mutable reference
```

The first variant is absolutely immutable (without taking internal mutability of `Cell` and such into account) - you can neither change what `a` points to nor the object it currently references.

The second variant allows you to change `a` to point somewhere else but it doesn't allow you to change the object it points to.

The third variant does not allow to change `a` to point to something else but it allows mutating the value it references.

And the last variant allows both changing `a` to reference something else and mutating the value this reference is currently pointing at.

Taking the above into account you can see where `mut a: &T` can be used. For example, you can write a search of a part of a string in a loop for the further usage like this:

```
let mut s: &str = source;
loop {
    // ... whatever
    s = &source[i..j];
}
// use the found s here
```